# ubuntu server 18.04 ssh failure

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I can't connect to my server with any client until I ping from the server the ip of the client.

I've tried to restart the service, restart the server... and the only thing that it looks that work is ping the client machine.

the connection on the server is by lan and the rest of the clients over wifi.

Anyone know what it could be?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided, I can only guess. This can happen for any of **three** reasons:

#### Reason #1

There is a duplicate IP to the server's IP. Please check your network IPs and make sure to fix the duplicate IP by changing it to something different.

#### Reason #2

The server is out of range for the client machines because of one of the following:

- Multiple vlans are configured on the switch and the server is on a different vlan than the client machines. Please check if vlans are configured on your switch and make sure the server and the client machines are on the same vlan.
- The subnet masks for the server and the client machines do not match. For example the servers subnet mask might be `255.255.0.0` while the clients subnet mask might be `255.255.255.0`. Please check the subnet masks on the server and the client machines and make sure they are all on the same IP class and the same subnet mask.

#### Reason #3

There is some sort of security device in between the server and the client machines for example a firewall a proxy or an antivirus... etc ( *wireless access points with `ap isolation enabled` included* ). Please check and make sure nothing is blocking or interfering with the connection between the server and the client machines.

Comment: I think it was reason # one.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Galindo I am glad it helped.