# Can't access apache web server locally after changing router

Tags: apache2, lan

Totally lost. I have an apache reverse proxy setup serving 3 web servers. Everything has worked fine until I I recieved a new router from my ISP. Now I can only access my webservers from remote locations. I can't access them from my local network. My server configs haven't changed so I have to assume it's the router but Can't resolve it. It's a Technicolor C1100T. Any help would be greatly appriciated as it would be so much easier to update web sites. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How do you connect both server and client machines via cable or wireless?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1167818/968501

Comment: Raffa - Thanks for the question. It's mixed. Some are wifi and others hardwired. The servers and proxy are all wired though. And hardwired to the router.

Comment: Then check the linked answer in my comment above and especially see if `ap isolation` is enabled under wireless options and disable it. This will prevent connection from wireless clients to the servers if it is enabled.

Comment: Raffa - Thanks for the suggestions. Not seeing any option for ap isolation in the router.

Comment: Try connecting your client by cable and see if it can reach the server this way? If yes, then it is most likely a wireless setting issue. If not check the IP of the client and see if it is in the same subnet with the server.

Comment: Raffa - Ok, well no luck there. Definetly on the same subnet. But hardwiring to the router didn't help. What's your thought's on this.... I'm wondering if it's not a NAT issue with the new router or, pehaps, I never really configured my vhosts on servers or proxy for local access but maybe the other router was "more lenient" per se. I can use the server IP (sort of) to reach them. but usually fails after the front page??

Comment: Ok, new development. On one client machine, I edited the etc/hosts file to add the ip of the proxy and hostname of server 1. It takes a long time, but finally gets to the front page but no farther when navigationg by hostname??

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So what fixed it was adding my reverse proxy IP and server hostnames in my client machine /etc/hosts file. Now it navigates fine. But 2 things I don't understand 1. do I need to go to every client and edit the hosts file (That seems inefficient) and 2. why was this never a problem with the previous router? So not completely solved, but functional for now.

Comment: This looks like a DNS resolution issue. To resolve local host-names you need the IP of your local router to be present in the list of DNS servers on your clients. Check with `systemd-resolve --status` and see under the link you use to connect to the router.