# How do I get ssh to start working?

Tags: server, ssh, iptables, routing, router

I turn an unused laptop into an Ubuntu server and everything was working great. I connected to it through ssh on my Windows 10 computer and was able to set up and access Nextcloud to upload all my files. Later the same day I went to upload some more files and I can not access Nextcloud through the URL so I tried to ssh into the server and it says,

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.82 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I then pinged the IP and this is what it shows.

```
Pinging 192.168.1.82 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.105: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.82:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

(the .82 is my server and the .105 is my windows computer)

I am new to working in with Linux and I decided to set up an Ubuntu server to help learn my way around but after hours of searching I could not find anything that helped.

I set the IP to be static and if I `ssh 127.0.0.1` everything runs fine. I disabled the firewall on the server to see if that would help but still no luck.

This is an image of details from my router about the server. The IP is set to be static, but it shows that the status is off for some reason. I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it.

[image: details from my router about the server]

This is `ipconfig` from my windows computer.

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : attlocal.net
 IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2600:1700:eef1:8500::732
 IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2600:1700:eef1:8500:f872:b6be:1554:daea
 Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2600:1700:eef1:8500:68b0:5914:b408:55e5
 Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f872:b6be:1554:daea%4
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.105
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::3a3b:c8ff:fe26:7dcd%4
                                     192.168.1.254
```

```
home_server@homeserver:~$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:d0:d2:0d:bb  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 85454  bytes 6965740 (6.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 85454  bytes 6965740 (6.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wls8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.82  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 84:ef:18:b4:4c:fe  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27285  bytes 3338490 (3.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5750  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59891  bytes 13749849 (13.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Does it work if you go to the server, not the Windows computer, and type `ssh 127.0.0.1`? Have you set up a static IP address for the server? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1422026/edit) and add all these information.

Comment: Yeah that looks like a routing problem, not an "ssh not working" problem

Comment: Did you setup your server to have a static IP address and did you also setup your router to have the IP reservation for that IP address so it doesn't give that address out to anyone else?

Comment: It is also very odd that you see 0% packet loss when none of the packets got to the destination.  It should be 100% packet loss.

Comment: I did set up the server to have a static IP but I did not set up a router reservation for that IP. I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: It does work if I ssh to 127.0.0.1 from the server.

Comment: Please edit your question and include full IP configuration (IP address, netmask and routing table) both from Ubuntu and from Windows machine.

Comment: Related: [ubuntu server 18.04 ssh failure](https://askubuntu.com/a/1167818/968501)

Comment: I don't have any of the above issues with the related link from @Raffa. This morning I checked my router and it showed that the server was active again. I am now able to ssh and connect to the web console on my windows laptop. Does anybody know why it would go active and inactive?

Comment: It looks like the problem solved itself.

Comment: I believe the issue has solved itself. After monitoring it most of the day the server has not gone inactive again. Thank you all for the help! It has been a great encouragement to know I'm not alone in fixing everything.

Comment: AAAAAAAANnnnnddddd it happened again. My router shows that the server is connected but inactive. I cant even ping the IP anymore. When I log into the server it shows that the web console is still running and that the IP is still the same.

Comment: I don't know what broke but now I cant connect the server to the internet and it changed the name of connection when I do the ip a command. I am going to post a new question because it get a little more complicated. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Try disabling any power saving on the laptop.  I have seen issues with Wifi, especially USB dongles, that will power down if they feel there isn't enough activity on them for a while then they will become unreachable.